# Condition for the congruence class to form a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, +)$ be an abelian group  where $n$ is nonzero composite integer

$$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\{\bar{0}, \bar{1}, .... , \overline{n-1} \}$$

Now the Lagrange theorem tells us if we want to construct a subgroup $H$ of $G$ then the order of $H$ must divide $n$. Since $n$ is composite, there is always a non-trivial subgroup since $G$ is abelian.
As we know every subgroup contains the identity $\bar{0}$ and every element has an inverse in $H$ and also $H$ should be closed under $+$ .
For example $H=\{\bar{0}, \bar{6}, \overline{12} , \overline{18} \}$ is subgroup of 
$\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$ all the element of $H$ are divisible by $6$ so the congruence class   have a  common property.

My question is what is the condition for the congruence class to form a subgroup of 
$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ ?does the congruence class have a common property when they form a subgroup ?

Comment: For every divisor $d$ of $ n$, $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z,+)$ has a subgroup of order $d$

Comment: But what is the common property of the elements of this subgroups

Comment: they're multiples of $\overline {n/d}$

Comment: d is the order the subgroup of the elements in which they are multiple of $\bar{n/d}$

Comment: Can you give me a reason why the elements of the subgroup should be multiple of $\bar{n/d}$